# yii2 ActiveForm field placeholder

Tags: php, yii2, field

I want to create form using yii2 ActiveForm. Here is my code:

```
<?php
$form = \yii\widgets\ActiveForm::begin([
    'options' => [
        'class' => 'form-inline'
        ]
]);
?>
<div class="form-group">
     <label class="sr-only" for="example">Email</label>
     <?php echo $form->field($model, 'email', [
           'inputOptions' => ['autofocus' => 'autofocus', 'class' => 'form-control transparent']
     ])->textInput(['placeholder' => "Enter Your Email"])->input('email')->label(false); ?>
</div>


<button type="submit" class="subscr-btn btn btn-primary btn-fill">Join</button>
<?php \yii\widgets\ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

which generates this html:

```
<form id="w0" class="form-inline" action="/example" method="post">
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail2">Email address</label>
    <div class="form-group field-subscriber-email required">
        <input type="email" id="subscriber-email" class="form-control transparent" name="Subscriber[email]"
               autofocus="autofocus">
        <div class="help-block"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="subscr-btn btn btn-primary btn-fill">Join</button>
```

Everything is ok, but where is placeholder?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Put it inside `input()` method as second parameter - [reference](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-activefield.html#input()-detail)

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label class="sr-only" for="example">Email</label>
     <?php echo $form->field($model, 'email', [
           'inputOptions' => ['autofocus' => 'autofocus', 'class' => 'form-control transparent']
     ])->textInput()->input('email', ['placeholder' => "Enter Your Email"])->label(false); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: It also can be put in `textInput` : `...)->textInput(['placeholder' => "Enter Your Email"])`

Comment: Yes true. You can edit the answer and add your note (better with reference). It is relevant.